# python plotly create a color scale related to max and min number of value

Tags: python, mapbox, plotly

This is a code, I try to show a car speed for each point.

```
import plotly.plotly as py
from plotly.graph_objs import *

mapbox_access_token = 'MAPBOX API KEY'


data = Data([
    Scattermapbox(
        lat=dataframe_monday_morning['latitude'],
        lon=dataframe_monday_morning['longitude'],
        mode='markers',
        marker=Marker(
            size=5,
            color =dataframe_monday_morning['speed'],
            colorscale= 'YlOrRd',

            #opacity=0.3,
            symbol = 'circle',

        ),

    )
])
layout = Layout(
    autosize=True,
    hovermode='closest',
    width=1300,
        margin=go.Margin(
        l=0,
        r=0,
        b=0,
        t=0
        ),
    height=700,
    mapbox=dict(
        accesstoken=mapbox_access_token,
        bearing=0,#
        center=dict(
            lat=-36.7526,
            lon=174.7274
        ),
        pitch=0,
        zoom=16.2,
        style='dark',


    ),
)

fig = dict(data=data, layout=layout)
py.iplot(fig, filename='Multiple Mapbox')
```

but when I try

```
color =dataframe_monday_morning['speed']
```

code choose in current data min and max speed then gives me a graph. In data, some speed data gaps are very big so I would like to create a colour scale between my speed value.
(e.g  If you choose max speed 200km/h your other 30km/h and 90km/h looks similar colour but normally really different speed )

[image]

My question is how can I create a scale for choosing a colour for speed?

**EDIT:**

This is an example of data I edited.

```
13  1.464301e+10    2015-11-15 18:28:50 191 10051   76  -36.817540  174.750526      
14  1.464298e+10    2015-11-15 18:27:20 209 10051   48  -36.806104  174.759209      
15  1.464180e+10    2015-11-15 17:41:27 171 10051   0   -36.718553  174.713503  
16  1.464186e+10    2015-11-15 17:43:44 172 10051   25  -36.720747  174.713897  
17  1.464238e+10    2015-11-15 18:05:36 137 10051   5   -36.753691  174.728945  
18  1.464199e+10    2015-11-15 17:49:22 170 10051   0   -36.728252  174.715084  
19  1.464279e+10    2015-11-15 18:20:41 153 10051   20  -36.787389  174.752337  
20  1.464229e+10    2015-11-15 18:01:47 146 10051   16  -36.749369  174.724865  
21  1.464298e+10    2015-11-15 18:27:39 216 10051   51  -36.807940  174.757603  
22  1.464254e+10    2015-11-15 18:11:35 162 10051   36  -36.765195  174.739728  
23  1.464301e+10    2015-11-15 18:28:37 197 10051   66  -36.815369  174.751177
```

Comment: How about define high and low RGB values, then do linear interpolation?

Comment: edited.  Hey @AnthonyKong not RGB but I tried HSL code because HSL first values is integer so you can easy to declare it. c= ['hsl('+str(dataframe_monday_morning['speed'])+',50%'+',50%)']  but I could not embed in my code –

Comment: Can you add some example data to get a standalone example?

Comment: Hey @MaximilianPeters I edited my question

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not 100% sure if I got the question right but you could try adding

```
showscale=True,
cmax=200,
cmin=0
```

to your `Marker` object to get a graph with a colorbar with fixed [max](https://plot.ly/python/reference/#scatter-marker-cmax) and [min](https://plot.ly/python/reference/#scatter-marker-cmin) values.

[image]

Comment: This is cool! I tried many times this is working if your data over the limit doesn't matter programme is giving you end of limit colour. Thank you!